# Async load COM object

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-interface, asynchronous

I have a COM object with a GUI-component, lets call it "FileViewer". This FileViewer component can load a file by using a method, lets call it "LoadFile", that needs to use the UI thread to work. To use LoadFile, the FileViewer have to already been added and loaded into the GUI. 
The problem is that the files that you load with LoadFile can be really big which causes the application UI to freeze for multiple seconds, making for a terrible user experience.

My quesion is: Is there anyway to call this LoadFile async without locking the UI thread even thought it requiring a UI thread to load.

What I've tried:

```
    //My standard approach of doing things async
        public async btnPressed (){    
           await new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => {
              myFileViewer.LoadFile("C:\...");   //This still freezes the UI thread
           });
        }  


    //Maybe could prevent locking if it's not visible
        myFileViewer.Parent = null;   
        myFileViewer.Visible = false;
        myFileViewer.LoadFile("C:\...");   //This still freezes the UI
        myFileViewer.Parent = this;
        myFileViewer.Visible = true;


    //Maybe could create the viewer in a new window "TestProxy" with a new "UI thread", load the file and then insert the viewer back into my first window
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {   
           new TestProxy().Show();  
           TestProxy.CreateViewerAndLoadFile("C:\...");  //Does actually not freeze my application
           System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start(); 
//this version actually worked, but the problem is that there seem to be no way to move the viewer back into my original window after loading it into this new one
```

I'm very sure that the Viewer class in itself does not have any support for doing LoadFile async, so I am more interested in a general solution of the problem. Just dosn't feel like it should be something that's impossible to do.

PS:
The name of the GUI component is "AxInventorViewControl" which I create an instance of and "LoadFile" is infact a row of code axInventorViewControl1.FileName = filePath;

Comment: No, there is no obvious solution for this beyond hiding the UI and an hourglass until it is done.  Consider calling Autodesk for support.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah ok, thanks. I'll try that next then

Comment: Does the file viewer only take a filename or can you give the data as a stream as well?

Comment: @Otterprinz It only takes a filename